# JWPlayer get current subtitle or subtitle index

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, jwplayer6

Is there a way to get current (@current position) subtitle or at least index in JWPlayer via Javascript API ????

Thanks

For example, in image below I want to trigger something once text/subtitle on the screen.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sure thing:

```
jwplayer().getCurrentCaptions();
```

This is on - http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413089-javascript-api-reference

Comment: Thanks Ethan appreciate your effort , but actually I don't want the select captions, I actually want list of subtitles for the selected caption, actually I am try to print subtitle out the video in different div ...

Comment: Sure, that is - jwplayer().getCaptionsList();

Comment: OK, i think i am not explaining it well, this gives me option available to select, but I want is list of subtitles for the selected caption. I want to know when actually the subtitle (not the caption selected) is change like at what time text/subtitle started and when ended ... hope I have explained it well if not let me know I will try to add some snapshots or code ...

Comment: I am a bit confused. Subtitles essentially are captions. If you have 4 different captions tracks, getCaptionsList() will give you each available subtitle to pick from.

Comment: From the API (linked above): getPosition() Returns the current playback position in seconds, as a number. So you can check the current position, compare that to your track file, and you'll know what caption is being displayed (if any).

Comment: Ah yes, this will definitely work, then. You need to use both API calls in order to do this.